# Ring homomorphism extension from $k[x]$ to $k(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I've been trying to prove that if $k$ is an algebraically closed field, $V$ is a $k$-vector space, $\dim_k(V)$ is infinite, and $f:V\to V$ is a linear operator such that $f-rI$ is invertible for all $r\in k$, then the ring homomorphsm

\begin{align} p:k[x]&\to\mathrm{End}_k(V)\\ g(x)&\mapsto g(f)  \end{align}

can be extended to a ring homomorphism

\begin{align} \hat{p}:k(x) &\to\mathrm{End}_k(V)\\ \frac{g(x)}{s(x)}&\mapsto g(f)s(f)^{-1}  \end{align}

It is like universal property of localization ring (which I don't use because I learned this is just for commutative rings, but $\mathrm{End}_k(V)$ is not). I could prove $\hat{p}$ is well defined, also $\hat{p}(a+b)=\hat{p}(a)+\hat{p}(b)$. My problem is with $\hat{p}(ab)=\hat{p}(a)\hat{p}(b)$, because without commutativity I get stuck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The subring generated by $f$ is commutative. You can use that. In fact, you will need to use that to show that $\hat{p}(ab) = \hat p(a)\hat p(b)$. By the way, the condition you need for non-commutative rings is called the [Ore condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition) which is exactly the condition you need to rewrite $uv^{-1} xy^{-1} = ux' (v')^{-1}y^{-1}$.

Comment: Also, if you want to show that $xy^{-1} = y^{-1}x$, you can multiply by $y$ on both sides first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So some ingredients:

1. Show that if $A$ and $B$ and $C$ and $D$ all commute with each other, then $A + B$ commutes with $C + D$ and $AB$ with $CD$. And also $AB$ with $C + D$ and so on.
2. with these base cases + induction, you can show that polynomials in $f$ commute with other polynomials in $f$

Possibly you've already done this.

3. you want to show that the fractions commute as well. E.g. if $x$ and $y$ are polynomials in $f$ then $xy = yx$ implies $y^{-1}(xy)y^{-1} = y^{-1}(yx)y^{-1}$, which shows that $x$ commutes with $y^{-1}$.
4. Similarly, you can show that $x, y, x^{-1}, y^{-1}$ all commute with each other.

Comment: You said you could prove that $\hat p$ is well-defined so I didn't elaborate on this. Polynomials over an algebraically closed field split into linear factors $(t - r_1)(t - r_2) \cdots$ and the hypothesis says that this product is invertible with $t = f$.